# Ember Data not sending data on submit

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

When I'm submitting the form, I get the following response:

`{"data":{"attributes":{"title":null,"description":null},"type":"cards"}}`

I'm not sure why I am getting `title` and `description` as null.

`routes/cards/new.js`:

```
actions: {
  save() {
    const newCard = this.get('store').createRecord('card', this.get('model'));
    newCard.save().then((card) => {
      this.transitionTo('cards.all');
    });
  },
  cancel() {
    this.transitionTo('cards');
  }
}
```

`templates/cards/new.hbs`:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Title:</label>
    {{input type="text" value=model.title}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Body:</label>
    {{textarea rows="5" value=model.description}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <button {{action 'save'}}>Speichern</button>
    <button {{action 'cancel'}}>Abbrechen</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Repo link: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client

Comment: Try `console.log(this.get('model'))`. It seems that call may not be returning the model. It's been a while since I've used ember, but I'm not sure you can assign model values in your view like that. I think you may need to call the model's `set()` method.

Comment: doing a `console.log(this.get('model'))` just prints the model function.

Comment: Oh yeah....sorry. Try `console.log(this.get('model.title'))`. I think what you need to do is give you text input value a seperate binding, then store that binding to your model before you submit your data as shown in this example http://code.runnable.com/UmhZmnll6X4OAAAq/how-to-bind-models-with-views-and-controllers-in-ember-js-for-jquery-javascript-handlebars-js-and-html5. Again, it's been a while since I've used ember so this may not be completely accurate, or things may have changed (as they often do with ember).

Comment: Could you check in chrome devtools the request sent by ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing title and description from your `.hbs` to the route properly. You are creating the model after you fire the action save. Change `model.title` for `title` and do the same for the description. Pass them up to your route: `{{ save title description }}`. Then define two parameters in your save action like: `save(title, description)`. I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: this approach looked best to me when i hit a block with the other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I usually do in my routes:

```
setupController(controller /*, model */ ) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.set(controller, 'newCard', {}); //newCard is an empty object
},
actions: {
    save(newCard) {
        Ember.assert('Model is missing or undefined', newCard);
        let newCard = this.store.createRecord('card', newCard);
        newCard.save().then(( /* response */ ) => {
            this.transitionTo('cards.all');
        }, (error) => {
            //handle error
        });
    }
}
```

And in your template you could do something like this:

```
<form id="save" {{action "save" newCard on="submit"}}>
    {{input name="title" id="title" value=newCard.title type="text"}}
    <button class="button" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.  Jeff

Answer (score 1):

In comment you mentioned

> doing a console.log(this.get('model')) just prints the model function

That's the answer to your question!. since in route you might have model hook function. so this.get('model') will return function instead of model.
So create controller for cards/new.js and you can move existing save actions. this should work.

Comment: at the end, i followed this approach.

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh still you would like to keep actions in route then you add the below line in setupController()  --> this.set('NewCardModel',model);  and in save method you can replace this.get('model') to this.get('NewCardModel') ...Hope this helps.